# Tomcat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOnEntry removeSession() method is not invoked

Tags: java, apache, session, tomcat, single-sign-on

The **org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOnEntry** class of Tomcat 8.0.24 has been overridden in our codebase. Basically the overridden addSession() & removeSession() methods have some additional logging statements & session count per user code.The addSession() is also attaching the Tomcat **SingleSignOnListener** to every created session,just like the parent class method.

We are using Tomcat's FormAuthenticator to perform user authentication. Now,the addSession() method is getting properly called when the user logs in. However, the removeSession() is not getting called when the session expires from a timeout. As a result, we are ending up with an incorrect sessions count.

I am not able to understand why the SingleSignOnListener is not getting called when session times out.It's the listener which invokes the removeSession() on a destroy event.

Debugging the code, I have found out that although Tomcat's "**destroySession**" sessionEvent is getting fired on the attached listener, it is not responding with the appropriate removeSession() method. Any thoughts on what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: super.removeSession() in the correct overwritten method is missing?

Comment: `SingleSignOnListener.sessionEvent(SessionEvent event) --> SingleSignOn.sessionDestroyed(this.ssoId, session) -->SingleSignOn.removeSession(String ssoId, Session session) --> SingleSignOnEntry.removeSession(session)` is the ideal container flow.      However,we have subclassed SingleSignOn & SingleSignOnEntry & overridden removeSession() of SingleSignOnEntry. We have included the parent removeSession() logic in the overriden method alongwith our custom logic